# intl extension missing

Tags: php, symfony, int

I am working on a project using PHP with Symfony. I have my intl.dll file present in wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext . In my php.ini file I have

```
 extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/"
```

and the intl.dll file is also enabled

but still I get the following error.

```
 The Symfony\Component\Locale\Stub\StubIntlDateFormatter::setLenient() is not implemented. Please install the 'intl' extension for full localization capabilities.
```

can anyone help me what should I do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Enable extension `php_intl`.

And copy `ic*.dll` files from `php` folder to `apache/bin` folder:

`copy D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\ic*.dll D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\`

As it suggested in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the file located in apache.
(bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini)

Remove the semicolon from the line :
;extension=php_intl.dll

Wamp seems to load the configuration from this file and not from the one in the php directory.

Comment: If it's enabled in the both files (the one from the apache directory, and the one from the directory php) I have no more clue, sorry.