# intl extension php_intl.dll with wamp

Tags: php, wamp, moodle

I want to use Moodle, but I get an error during the installation process:

> php_extension->intl->should be installed and enabled for best results.
>
> Intl extension is used to improve internationalization support, such as locale aware sorting.

When I click on the link, I get the error message above: `http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/admin/environment/php_extension/intl`

I followed that link, but I still get the same error. If anyone has any ideas, please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [intl extension: installing php\_intl.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll)

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem a few days ago.

You have to copy all the files (all files starts with `icu*`):

```
icudt.dll
icudt46.dll
icuin.dll
icuin46.dll
icuio.dll
icuio46.dll
icule.dll
icule46.dll
iculx.dll
iculx46.dll
icutest.dll
icutest46.dll
icutu.dll
icutu46.dll
icuuc.dll
icuuc46.dll
```

From:

```
<wamp_installation_path>/bin/php/php5.4.3/
```

To:

```
<wamp_installation_path>/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/bin/
```

And you also need to enable intl in php.ini file (uncomment this line):

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

And restart the server. It should works fine.

Of course, you need to replace the folder names with your own.

Comment: heyAthlan:-where i get these files.i search on C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin and C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext not found such type of files.there is no icu type files on these folers

Comment: As I mentioned, you can find them directly on:
`<wamp_installation_path>/bin/php/php5.4.3/` (not `ext` subdirectory). I have checked it for you for WAMP 2.2.

Comment: Using Wamp, I can only find `icu*46.dll` files, no unversionned files found. Any ideas?

Comment: See this post for the correct solution for versions of WAMPServer > WAMPServer 2.4

Comment: I've been trying to make it work for Magento since yesterday. You are God. Thank you thank you thank you. I have WAMP for Windows 64 bits, Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12 and this solution worked for me.

Comment: In WAMPServer 3.3 php.ini uncomment `extension=intl`

Answer (score 4):

Recently, newer versions of PHP 5.5 releases have **php_intl.dll** also linking (loading) MSVCP110.dll, in addition to the more common MSVCR110.dll (both are C/C++ runtime DLLs that provide common functions).

Before, you could just include file MSVCR110.dll somewhere in a directory of the PATH instead of installing the full set of VC++ 2012 Redistributable DLLs, and Apache + PHP + PHP extensions like php_intl.dll would all load.

If PHP is giving you this error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library C:/wamp/php/ext/php_intl.dll – **The specified module could not be found.**

There are two things you have to do:

1. Instead of copying the various icu*.dll files from PHP's folder into Apache's bin folder, just include the PHP directory into the system's PATH variable.
2. Install the full Microsoft VC++ 2012 Runtime Redistributable package. Make sure to get the 32 bit version for 32 bit PHP builds.

See more about this issue here - [Unable to load or find PHP extension php_intl.dll](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/unable-to-load-or-find-php-extension-php_intl-dll)

Answer (score 0):

Copy your `icu*` files to `<wamp_installation_path>/bin/apache/apachexxxxx/bin/`

This worked for me.

Comment: This is just the same as [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16372984/1402846).

Answer (score 0):

I tried many options (including the ones suggested by Moodle) to no avail; the VC++ redistributable helped me.

*Please note that you may have to install x86 version even when you may be having a 64 bit OS.*

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145