# The requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system (SonataAdminBundle) in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, intl

I try to install the sandbox but I get the following error from composer:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Installing
>   dependencies from lock file Your requirements could not be resolved to
>   an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- Installation request for sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.1.0.`

- sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.1.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.`
```

Problem 2

```
- sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.1.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.`

- sonata-project/news-bundle 2.1.x-dev requires sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.1.* -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.1.0.
- Installation request for sonata-project/news-bundle 2.1.
```

Comment: Hi, have u active intl in your php.ini ?

Comment: On Linux: php5-intl installed?

Comment: yes i activated intl in php.ini

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem while I was installing new Magento 2.0, after different hit and trials, I manged to solve it by following these steps:

I copied all **icu*** files from php directory to Appache directory, and it worked.

Php direcotry:

> WAMP\bin\php\php5.5.12

Appache Directory:

> WAMP\bin\apache\apache2.4.9

Make sure to un-comment following line in php.ini file:

> extension=ext/php_intl.dll

Answer (score 12):

Linux user

```
yum install php-intl
```

Comment: Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`

Comment: homebrew: `brew install php55-intl`

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 use
sudo apt-get install php-intl

Comment: Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl`

Answer (score 9):

Like **@Hugehornet** pointed out - you should enable this extension in **php.ini** by **uncommenting** this line: `extension=ext/php_intl.dll`

If you use wamp's interface for this task you are actually updating the **php.ini** file located in apache's directory.

Example: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini

Composer is using the one located in the php's installation directory.

Example: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini

You should manually edit the latter and restart the wamp server.

Comment: In my case I didn't have the line at all in my php.ini, so I've just added it, but without "ext/" => extension=php_intl.dll, and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable the intl extension in php just as the error says.
In your php.ini file, uncomment the line `extension=ext/php_intl.dll` or something like this.

Edit : note that if you are using wamp or something like this, you should be aware of the fact that the php.ini file in the wamp config is not necessarily the one used by composer.

Comment: yes, i am using WAMP, & already enable intl extension of extension=ext/php_intl.dll by uncommenting it in  php.ini and  still it giving me errors

Comment: What kind of wamp do you have ? WampServer ? uWamp ?

Comment: Look at this and see if it resolves your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp

Answer (score 3):

First of all be sure that your server is isung x86 build (intl not working with x64), then:

- activate intl extension in `php.ini` directly
- copy all `icu*.dll` form php directory to apache directory
- make sure your console using the same php folder you just configured
  [source](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/issues/32#issuecomment-10745894).

In my windows system I have two `php.ini` files at the flowing paths:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apachex.y.z\bin
```

I don't know which one is in your path. Just make sure to add the extension in both of them to eliminate any doubt.

Answer (score 3):

I am on a Mac OS X Yosemite, and I fix this error

> **the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system**

by running the following commands :

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php54-mcrypt
```

Comment: Do you use Xampp or WAMPP on your Mac OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 2):

If intl has already been enabled and it doesn't works, add your PHP directory in the Path environment variable, then restart your server.
(for example C:\Program Files\wamp\bin\php\phpX.XXX.XXX for wamp)

It has worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, Debian, and related Linux distributions

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

to install the extension for the default PHP version.
For other versions a variation like `apt-get install php7.3-intl` will choose the correct extension if the version provided is correct.

Comment: That's not really accurate, if your repo has php 7.4 and you have 7.2 for example, it'll install php 7.4-intl, not to mention not everyone is running a system that has apt, or even linux.