# How to specify folder where to search DLL files in Apache?

Tags: php, windows, apache

I resolved the problem of loading php_intl.dll library in PHP by copying files as explained in the Athlan's answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16372984/99256

I don't think that copying the files is particularly nice. There should be a directive in Apache to say "load DLL libraries from folder XY". How can I do that?

My setup:

- Windows
- Apache2
- PHP 5.4

Comment: What are you using? It is better to use WAMPServer or XAMPP!

Comment: I use Uniform Server. However, I don't see how it is relevant here.

Comment: Okay, WAMP has a module to load custom DLLs. That's the reason I asked. :) It is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses the PATH to search for shared libraries / DLLs that are loaded without an explicit path (dependencies of explicitly loaded DLLs).

Apache isn't doing anything with these DLLs, so there's no directive relating to them.