# Symfony2 install phpDocumentor

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, phpdocumentor2

I want to install phpdocumentor to my Symfony 2.4 project, so I added this two lines to my composer.json:

```
"require": {
   //my old requires
   "phpdocumentor/template-abstract": "~1.2",
   "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.1.*@dev"
}
```

whene I execut php composer.phar update, i have these errors:

```
 Problem 1
- phpdocumentor/template-abstract 1.2.1 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
- phpdocumentor/template-abstract 1.2 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for phpdocumentor/template-abstract ~1.2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-abstract[1.2, 1.2.1].
```

although I installed php_xsl in my php extensions?!!
Thank you.

Comment: What is the location of the php.ini file in which you have the php_xsl extension enabled? Sometimes webservers use a different php.ini than composer, so you can have the extension enabled for your website (i.e. shows up in phpinfo()) but not for the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I work in my local machine i installed wampserver 2.4 and i activated php_xsl from its graphic interface.

Comment: Enabling for WAMP doesn't necessarily mean that it is enabled for composer. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp.

Comment: Sorry, I did what mentioned in topic: (copie all icu* to my apache bin folder) but I have the same problem !!!

Comment: what's the output of `php -m | grep xsl` and `php -i | grep ini`? compare the location of the `php.ini` file with the one you see when accessing a php-file with `phpinfo()` from your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264003/cant-install-phpdocumentor-via-composer/23332688#23332688).. might as well elucidate.

Basically you also need to *enable the extension in the php.ini file used by PHP CLI* as this is the one composer uses when you run it on the command line.

( Mine is at: *C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini* )

Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

@Mohamed: I was getting the same problem few days back but when I tried the following command it then worked successfully.This will update your composer.phar file.

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with a composer version. https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/587