# Can't install phpDocumentor via Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, documentation-generation, package-managers

In composer.json I've got

```
{
    "require":
    {
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "*"
    }
}
```

It's what is there because I'm trying to install phpDocumentor into an isolated folder with `./composer.phar install` command. But what I'm getting is

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-abstract ~1.2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-abstract[1.2, 1.2.1].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.1 requires phpdocumentor/template-abstract ~1.2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-abstract[1.2, 1.2.1].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.1.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-abstract ~1.2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-abstract[1.2, 1.2.1].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.2.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-abstract ~1.2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-abstract[1.2, 1.2.1].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.2 requires phpdocumentor/template-abstract ~1.2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-abstract[1.2, 1.2.1].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.4.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-abstract ~1.2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-abstract[1.2, 1.2.1].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.1 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.0 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.
    - phpdocumentor/template-abstract 1.2.1 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/template-abstract 1.2 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor * -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are missing the XSL extension in your PHP setup. You can see http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php for more information on installing that extension.

Please note that the XSL extension is not necessary for the default template; you can also choose to use the PHAR executable or the downloadable archive. These can be downloaded from https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases/latest. These two do not check for the XSL extension and can thus be safely used.

Comment: I needed the phpDoc's source to make some audacious edits to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try sudo apt-get install php5-xsl

Comment: This worked for me and allowed me to continue using Composer to manage the package, so I didn't have this one package managed separately from all my others :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily enable the XSL extension (since its included by default in php 5).

Locate the php.ini file and enable (uncomment)

> extension=php_xsl.dll

(on WAMP; click on the wamp icon -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_xsl)

Please DON'T FORGET to also *enable the extension in the php.ini file used by PHP CLI* ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file)) as this is the one composer uses when run on command line.

For Reference (from above link):

> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini is for the CLI PHP program, which you found by
>   running php on the terminal.
>
> /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini is for the php-cgi system which isn't
>   specifically used in this setup.
>
> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini is for the PHP plugin used by Apache. This
>   is the one you need to edit for changes to be applied for your Apache
>   setup.

Might be handy to restart the server afterwords.

PS: You may verify the extension's availability using:

> composer show -p

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update that currently(PHP 7.4) the line to uncomment in php.ini file is:

> ;extension=xsl

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't composer to install the PhpDocumentor!

Why? On the homepage, of the [Official PhpDocumentator website](https://www.phpdoc.org/), you can found:

> **But wait? What about Composer?**
>
> Ah, you discovered our secret. There is a phpDocumentor composer
> package that you could use to install phpDocumentor.
>
> However: phpDocumentor is a complex application, and its libraries are
> used in countless other libraries and applications (2 of our libraries
> have more than 150 million downloads each); and this means that the
> chances for a conflict between one of our dependencies and yours is
> high. And when I say high, it is really high.
>
> So, because of the above: **we do not endorse nor actively support
> installing phpDocumentor using Composer.**

Based on this, maybe is better to create a script to install it. Here is just a example:

```
wget https://phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor.phar
chmod 0755 phpDocumentor.phar
sudo mv phpDocumentor.phar /usr/local/bin/phpdoc
sudo apt install -y graphviz
```