# composer dependency stating it doesn't have php-xsl

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdocumentor2

A composer dependency is stating it doesn't have php-xsl. I'm trying to install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor, but it won't let me because of a requirement. So now I'm trying to install the requirement and I get this:

```
$ composer require phpdocumentor/template-zend
Using version ~1.3 for phpdocumentor/template-zend
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.2 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.1 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.0 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

PHP info:

```
xsl

XSL enabled
libxslt Version 1.1.28
libxslt compiled against libxml Version 2.9.1
EXSLT   enabled
libexslt Version    1.1.28
```

Or is it maybe telling me I need ext-xsl?  What is that? Or is it saying what it looks like to me, that I need PHP xsl?

This is different that the marked dup post, see my comment below as to why.

Comment: interesting, this is a dup post.  what do i do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264003/cant-install-phpdocumentor-via-composer

Comment: You can flag it as a duplicate. I've done it for you.

Comment: thanks, however its not a dup  actually, its basically very similar, but the different is that person doesnt have XSL intalled, however i do, you can see by looking at my phpinfo above.  so it is a DIFFERENT PROBLEM.  sorry.

Comment: What happens if you run `composer show -p ext-xsl` as suggested [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2789#issuecomment-36838218)?

Comment: `$ composer show -p ext-xsl



  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package ext-xsl not found



show [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [package] [version]`  thanks for the link, ill more into this tomorrow.  however please let me know if you see anything..

Comment: So maybe the solution in the post I linked in my previous comment will work for you...

Comment: Is composer using the same PHP that you're checking the info of?

Comment: @deceze yes composer is using the same php, good question

Answer (score 5):

Try running `php -m` to get a list of all loaded extensions and see if XSL is included in it (a quick `php -m | grep xsl` could save some search time).

If it's not the case, you should find out which INI file is used by running `php --ini`. Open this file and make sure this line is uncommented (without a `;` prefix):

```
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

Comment: yes xsl is included in the list, and as i stated, in teh php info -v you see it in there. not sure how if it was in there, it wouldnt exist using php -m, but i do see it doing that anyway.  thanks!