# Homebrew how to install php72-xsl?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, phpdoc

I'm trying to install `phpdocumentor` via composer with the following command:

```
composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master
```

Which throws me the following error:

> Problem 1
>      - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[dev-master].
>      - Conclusion: remove phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0
>      - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0
>       - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5].
>       - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, 4.3.0].
>       - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.1, 4.3.0].
>       - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.2, 4.3.0].
>       - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.3, 4.3.0].
>       - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 4.3.0].
>       - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.5, 4.3.0].
>       - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock == 4.3.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[4.3.0].

Searching on Google led me to the following question:

- [Can't install phpDocumentor via Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264003/cant-install-phpdocumentor-via-composer)

From the correct answer in the link I provided above, I know that the source of my problem is that I'm missing the XSL for my PHP. However, I don't know how to proceed on installing XSL for PHP 7.2. I'm running on MacOs with Homebrew and I tried to do the following:

```
brew install php72-xsl
```

I've noticed there's a `xsl` inside my `php.ini`:

```
;extension=xsl
```

However, when I uncomment it, I get the following warning:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: /usr/local/Cellar/php72/7.2.2_13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xsl (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php72/7.2.2_13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xsl, 9): image not found)

I've checked and the file does not exist. Actually the whole folder `extensions` does not exist.

Can someone let me know how I should proceed to install `xsl`?

Comment: Could you post the whole composer error please?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim I updated with the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brew-installed package `php72` includes the xsl extension. Please undo your manual change to the php.ini.

You seem to have an dependency issue with `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock`.

You can try the following

- remove phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock from your composer.json
- run `composer update` to update the `composer.lock`
- add your phpdocumentor dependency

  `composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor`
- re-add phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock

  `composer require --dev phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock`

If you don't have the phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock dependency in your composer.json, try to delete the composer.lock and the vendor folder

`rm -rf vendor composer.lock`

Then run `composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor`

This should resolve implicit version constraints with reflection-docblock

Comment: Hmm... However I have no `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock` inside my `composer.json`. Running `composer update` and re-run the install command leads to same error. I've also undone the manual change to my `php.ini`.

Comment: Removing the `vendor` and `composer.lock` solved the problem! Thanks.

Comment: Also be aware of the possibility of phpdocumentor and phpunit both having dependencies on *different* versions of reflection-docblock, which can sometimes block the two from installing side by side.  This could also manifest itself on type-resolver or reflection-common, but I see it happen more often against reflection-docblock.