# Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll'

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am attempting to connect from an android app to mySQL database within the WAMP server. I am getting this error consistently throughout my php_error log:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll'
             The specified module could not be found.

in Unknown on line 0
```

When I click on the Apache>Version>2.4.9 I get the 2 following errors as pop ups:

```
The program cant start because icuuc51.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem
```

and

```
PHP startup: unable to load dynamic library 'c/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll'
The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone know what is causing this or any potential solutions?

Comment: did you place the module in the specified location ?

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp

Comment: What do u mean by the module in the specified location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [intl extension: installing php\_intl.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll). It discusses both `php_intl.dll` and the various `icud*.dll` libraries.

Comment: If one of these answers is correct can you flag it as so

Comment: Sorry, I have not flagged any of the answers as of yet as I have not be able to find a solution

Answer (score 19):

This can be corrected very simply as follows.

Using the wampmanager menus do the following :-

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Version
```

and then click the version number, probably `2.4.9`

This will cause WAMPServer to rebuild of all the SYMLINK's in the apache2.4.9/bin folder and that will put the correct symlinks in there for these 2 extensions.

TO CORRECT THE SECOND ISSUE

Edit the `\wamp\script\config.inc.php` file and find the code that sets this variable `$phpDllToCopy` and replace it with this code.

```
$phpDllToCopy = array (
    'icudt52.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.6.a2
    'icuin52.dll',
    'icuio52.dll',
    'icule52.dll',
    'iculx52.dll',
    'icutest52.dll',
    'icutu52.dll',
    'icuuc52.dll',
    'icudt51.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.5.6
    'icuin51.dll',
    'icuio51.dll',
    'icule51.dll',
    'iculx51.dll',
    'icutest51.dll',
    'icutu51.dll',
    'icuuc51.dll',
    'icudt50.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.5
    'icuin50.dll',
    'icuio50.dll',
    'icule50.dll',
    'iculx50.dll',
    'icutest50.dll',
    'icutu50.dll',
    'icuuc50.dll',
    'icudt49.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.3/5.4
    'icuin49.dll',
    'icuio49.dll',
    'icule49.dll',
    'iculx49.dll',
    'icutest49.dll',
    'icutu49.dll',
    'icuuc49.dll',
    'libeay32.dll',
    'libsasl.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajout pour éviter unknown error
    'libintl.dll',
    'php5isapi.dll',
    'php5nsapi.dll',
    'ssleay32.dll',
    'php5ts.dll',
    'fribidi.dll', //[modif oto] - Ci-contre et dessous pour PHP 5.2.x
    'fdftk.dll',   // Peuvent être supprimés pour PHP 5.3.0 ou plus
    'libmcrypt.dll',
    'libmhash.dll',
    'libmysql.dll',
    'libmysqli.dll',
    'msql.dll',
    'ntwdblib.dll',
    'php5activescript.dll',
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the simplest way that I can test to ensure that WAMP is working? I am not sure if I am getting a problem with my android app or the server?

Comment: Your welcome. You will have to ask another question for that, or someone will flag this and close this question. Give lots of details about the new problem in the new question.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Explaination here :
https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/unable-to-load-or-find-php-extension-php_intl-dll

Comment: Thank you !!!! I migrated from an HDD to a SSD but just copied wamp files, and indeed that Visual C++ redistributable was not installed on my new hard drive. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to copy these files

```
icudt.dll
icudt46.dll
icuin.dll
icuin46.dll
icuio.dll
icuio46.dll
icule.dll
icule46.dll
iculx.dll
iculx46.dll
icutest.dll
icutest46.dll
icutu.dll
icutu46.dll
icuuc.dll
icuuc46.dll
```

to the location `<wamp_installation_path>/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/bin/`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp) for details.

Comment: No, in WAMPServer 2.5 this is now done with SYMLINKS. See my answer for the correct solution. Anyway he needs the icu V51 versions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the mentioned file (php_intl.dll) is under c:\wamp\bin\php5.5.12\ext folder.

If so, open the following file with notepad:

c:\wamp\bin\php5.5.12\php.ini

and check if you can find the following line (important: should not have ; sign before the word 'extension'):

extension=php_intl.dll

Comment: I have checked the two things you suggested and they are both there. Is there any other issue it could be? Thanks for your help

Comment: It could be the typical wamp-related issue, you should look at this thread: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,126105 ("left click the wampmanager icon -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9"). It recreates/resets the symbolic links might be causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please see the edit I made at the bottom of the question showing the errors that I get when I do so.

Comment: icuuc51.dll should be under C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12  (alternatively full re-install wamp if total stucked, or try to add c:\wamp\bin;c:\wamp\bin\php to your PATH manually from command prompt: setx path "%path%;c:\wamp\bin;c:\wamp\bin\php")

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when I installed wampserver 2.5 on windows10. So after some research and trying multiple solutions, I found following helpful:

This can be easily fixed by doing this with the wampmanager menus:-

1. (left click) wampmanager->Apache->Version -> 2.4.9 (Click on the version number)
2. Wait 3 seconds for wampmanager to rebuild the SYMLINKS and restart Apache

All fixed

Ref: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138288