# Cannot Start Wamp Server

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

For some unknown reason I cannot start WAMP server - The icon stays yellow no matter what:
Checked port 80, and it's not used. 
No Skype, no Firewall. 
Tried MANY solutions I suggested here in stackoverflow - absolutely nothing.
Tried to uninstall and reinstall - it worked for 10 minutes, then it didn't work again.

The only thing I'm changing is to include Virtual Hosts under httpd.conf. Checked every solution I could find on the net - nothing is working for me.

Maybe, just maybe it's because I previously installed PHP 5.5 apart from WAMP? If I go to PHP > PHP Extensions > then I can see there's a problem in php_opcache and php_enchant. When I click on them I get an error message that says: Could not execute menu item (internal error). [Execption] Could not perform service action: the service has not been started. The PHP Version I installed is 5.5.15. The PHP WAMP is 5.5.12... I don't have a clue how to uninstall PHP, and I couldn't find anything about that on the net.

PHP Error log says: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0

EDIT - It seems like the cause for the problem is me trying to include Virtual Host via httpd.conf file. When I excluded, like in default, WAMP is online again. Any suggestion of how to include virtual host and still get WAMP get online?

Comment: what do you mean, "wamp server"? The wamp control panel? apache? mysql? There's many components. did you check error logs for possible reasons?

Comment: I mean it's not connecting. I don't know why, and I also don't know what to do about those Error logs. There is the Error in PHP Error log: [26-Aug-2014 18:49:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Just a suggestion... While you can run all of this on your machine, if you're doing any real web development and not hosting your site on a Windows box also running WAMP (which you shouldn't), I would recommend a Vagrant box instead.  Basically, a virtual machine running the same OS and versions of software as your main servers can be used for development, right on your Windows machine.  Vagrant is a tool that manages this VM and makes it quick and easy to get started.  I highly recommend this route.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running on a corrupt install have you tried reinstalling the software?

Alternatively i would recommend using Xampp which basically offers the same service as Wampp only with a bit more ease of access (also allowing for Mecury mail service and an FTP server for remote access).

Comment: I already tried to uninstall and the reinstall. Twice. It's working for few minutes, but then when I stop the services for whatever reason I have, and then restart the services (all of them), It's not connecting, and the icon stays yellow. I will try to reinstall one last time, and if it wouldn't work, I'll switch to Xampp, but I have to say I used WAMP for one year now, and everything was OK...

Comment: Are you using a 64bit distro or 32 bits ? 
the some others are having issues using the 64bit distro for Wampp
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85378,printview,page=1

Comment: 64bit, but now I'm sure the problem is with me including httpd-vhosts.conf, because when i'm excluding it from httpd, WAMP is online again. But now the problem is - How can I use virtual host? :\

Answer (score 0):

The problem with php_intl can be corrected easily, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984913/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-c-wamp-bin-php-php5-5-12-ext-php-intl-dll)

In order to find out what Apache is complaining about with the Virtual Hosts definition look at the Windows Event Log or, launch a command window and

```
cd \wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin
httpd -t
```

This should give you filename and line number where your errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that port number anyway. Mine stays yellow if the port number is set to 80, even though WAMP says it's not being used by any other program.