# PHP Startup:Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll'- The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, wamp

I have downloaded wamp server from http://www.wampserver.com/en/ in my Windows 8 laptop which is a 32 bit system. 
On clicking on the pink wamp server icon on the desktop the i get the following error:

> PHP Startup:Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll'- The specified module
>   could not be found.

what should I do?

I have already tried uninstalling and re installing the program several times, but the same problem persists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php\_intl.dll'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984913/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-c-wamp-bin-php-php5-5-12-ext-php-intl-dll)

Answer (score 1):

copy the icu*.dll files to your apache's bin directory. If it is not working in bin directory then copy it in you apache's directory.

OR

You can add c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ in your system's PATH

Comment: i tried to copy the icu*.dll files as directed...still the same error persists

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on Mac. I installed PHP INTL using HomeBrew.

For php 7.1 install INTL with this terminal command:

> brew install php71-intl

Activate intl extension in php.ini. Use `php --ini` to check the configuration path.

> intl.default_locale = en_utf8
>
> intl.error_level = E_WARNING
>
> intl.use_exceptions = 0

Answer (score 0):

I added path to the PHP folder in the system PATH environment and it helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).