# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\php\\ext\\php_ldap.dll'

Tags: php, ldap

Windows 7
apache 2.4
php 5.6.31

```
c:/windows/php.ini

extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"

extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

gd2,mysql,mysqli, php_pdo_sqlite work. 
php_ldap.dll daesn't works.

apache error.log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\php\\ext\\php_ldap.dll'
```

Comment: Did you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548277/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-ldap-dll