# intl extension php_intl.dll with wamp error

Tags: wamp, intl

I'm getting Error PHP Extension intl not installed:

> PHP version 5.5.12 >

I checked in php.ini file it's already enabled..

Comment: I got solution from this link -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp/16372984#16372984

Thanks.

Comment: Should be closed as a duplicate, but Triage mode does not make it easy to flag as such. Kudos to Ajay for finding the answer to his question :-)

Comment: See below for correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is actually very simple.

Using the wampmanager menus you do this :-

```
(left click)wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9  (Click on 2.4.9)
```

This will rebuild the SYMLINKS in the Apache folder to the files that do and should only exist in the PHP{version} folder, and then restart Apache.

As of WAMPServer 2.4 SYMLINKS are created rather than copying these files from the PHP folder to the Apache folder.

Comment: RiggsFolly, thanks for your advice, it works for me!