# Symfony 2 - Install and enable the intl extension

Tags: php, windows, symfony, wamp

I'm using `WAMP in windows` and `Symfony 2.8`. I have install the `Twig Intl Extension` for translate Date in my templates.

In my wamp : PHP-> php.ini, I have this line `extension=php_intl.dll` whithout the `;`. I have add the `;` restart, and then delete it and restart but nothing change.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: have you checked with phpinfo() It should work if you remove the ;

Comment: Actually using such an old version is not too good. Better use Symfony 3.4

Comment: i can see it in my `phpinfo()`

Comment: Are you editing the correct `php.ini` file. Make sure you use the wampmanager menus to edit this file. `wampmanager->PHP->php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp/16372984#16372984)

Copy all your `icu*.dll` files to `wamp/www/bin/php/php.version/` in `wamp/www/bin/apache/apache.version/bin/`